# Why this is echoing just a first character in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

```
$fr = "hammad";
$frhammad = "nuthing";
echo $fr{$fr};

Output:
h
```

Whereas the expected output was

`"Nuthing"`

What Should be the format to echo "Nuthing"?

Comment: "$s"? Also, what do you *expect*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $x{$n} is standard syntax that treats the string $x as an array of characters, where $n is the numeric index position of a character in that aray. In your case the index position is identified by $fr, which is a non-numeric string, so PHP's loose typing is converting it to an integer 0, and so echoing the character at position 0... the first character of the string

**EDIT**

obligatory quote from the manual:

**String access and modification by character**

Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose. The functions substr() and substr_replace() can be used when you want to extract or replace more than 1 character.

Note: Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the same purpose.

**EDIT #2**

To answer your latest question from the comments:

> how would I concatenate the name of variables as I have given in it
>   question?

```
$fr = "hammad"; 
$frhammad = "nuthing"; 
$varName = 'fr'.$fr;
echo $$varName;
```

or

```
$fr = "hammad";
$frhammad = "nuthing";
echo ${'fr'.$fr};
```

Comment: Then how would I concatenate the name of variables as I have given in it question?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for variable-variable interpolation is:

```
$fr = "hammad";
$frhammad = "nuthing";
echo ${fr.$fr};
```

Comment: Note that this will issue a warning if the constant 'fr' is not defined, and warnings are enabled

Comment: @MarkBaker, you're right. Maybe he forgot to mention the Quotes around the 'fr'.